# Connecting to different on premise servers with the same logic app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, data-gateway

I was wondering if there is a way to use a logic app to get a task done on multiple  directories in different servers.

What i'm after is a way to get a task done in a looping manor. For example using a list to loop through, with the server and directory information specified, getting my specific task done on each server and its specified folder path.

Whats the best way to do this?

Maybe a Logic app or even a function?
I know Logic apps can connect to On premises servers by using the "On-Premises Data Gateway", but when a connection is set i'm not sure if there is a way to change it "while running / on the fly".

And using a Function, is it possible to reach an om premises path to run the task?

Comment: Yes, the connection can not be changed at the runtime. But if all your directories are on computers in same AD, you can connect to them all

Comment: Is there any possibility to do this with code in a function? I'm thinking using On-premises Data Gateway on a virtual server acting "hub"/"gateway" to the other servers? Then all i would have to do is using that gateway to access the other servers through path and permissions.